# Find $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-x\sqrt{n}$

Tags: limits

As the title suggests, I need to prove the $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  n\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-x\sqrt{n} = \frac{-x^2}{2}$$
I've tried to used things like L'hospitals but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean $\ln(\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{n}})$ or $\ln(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})$ ?

Comment: @Squirtle Using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%3D1000000000000000;+x%3D1000;+find+n*ln((1%2Bx)%2Fsqrt(n))-x*sqrt(n)), I'm pretty sure they mean $\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt n}\right)$.

Comment: Also, my instinct here is to factor out $\sqrt n$ to get the following: $$\sqrt n\left(\sqrt n \cdot \ln\left(1+\frac x {\sqrt n}\right)-x\right)=\sqrt n\left(\ln\left(1+\frac x {\sqrt n}\right)^{\sqrt n}-x\right)$$

Comment: As shown by the pair of answers below, 1. L'H can be made to work if one spends a nonzero amount of thought and ingeniosity to make the problem amenable to L'H, 2. this transformation step brings zero mathematical knowledge or expertise, neither about the problem nor unrelated to it, 3. powerful, flexible, all-around, easier methods exist, most notably Taylor expansions, to solve these.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put $t = 1/\sqrt{n}$ so that $n = 1/t^{2}$ and then we have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\log\left(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right) - x\sqrt{n}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1}{t^{2}}\log\left(1 + tx\right) - \frac{x}{t}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + tx) - tx}{t^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{1 + tx} - x}{2t}\text{ (via L'Hospital's Rule)}\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{x^{2}}{1 + tx}\notag\\
&= -\frac{x^{2}}{2}\notag
\end{align}
Thus L'Hospital's Rule works fine here.

Comment: "Thus L'Hospital's Rule works fine here" That is... L'H can be made to work if one spends a nonzero amount of thought and ingeniosity to make the problem amenable to L'H. Note that this transformation step brings zero mathematical knowledge or expertise, neither about the problem nor unrelated to it, and that powerful, flexible, all-around, easier methods exist, most notably Taylor expansions, to solve these.

Comment: @Did: Rightly said Taylor series is the most powerful and natural solution to such problems. I myself don't prefer the use of L'H but perhaps got carried away with the sentence of OP "I've tried to used things like L'hospitals but to no avail".

Comment: Why not give to the OP the right tools once and for all, instead of comforting their illusion that L'H would be the way to go?

Comment: @Did: Got it! Will take care the next time to emphasize that even if LH works it is better to avoid in preference to more natural approach of Taylor series. I think L'H is a big blocker in understanding because it reduces evaluation of limits to "mechanized differentiation and plugging the value of $x$ thereafter."

Comment: The last sentence of your comments neatly pinpoints the trouble. One can add to this (but at a secondary level) that L'H comes with some conditions and that these are often not even checked, which can lead to chaos.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it.

One knows that, when $t\to0$, $\ln(1+t)=t-\frac12t^2+o(t^2)$, hence, fixing $x$ and considering the limit $n\to\infty$, one gets $\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{x^2}{{2n}}+o\left(\frac1n\right)$.

Thus, $$n\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\sqrt{n}x=-\frac{x^2}{{2}}+o(1),$$
that is,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\ \left[n\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\sqrt{n}x\right]=-\frac{x^2}{2}.$$